# Increase maximum tracking distance of Kinect

Tags: kinect

So according to the Kinect v2 SDK specs, the maximum skeletal tracking distance is only 4.5M.

Is there any way to increase this distance, perhaps with reduced skeletal tracking accuracy since I only need to track the head?

Comment: Proooobably not without physical mods? That is, a lens or something. It'd probably be a tradeoff between distance and field of view. Don't know anything for certain though

Comment: Keep in mind [the Kinect's internal decision forest](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/real-time-human-pose-recognition-in-parts-from-a-single-depth-image/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fpubs%2F145347%2Fbodypartrecognition.pdf) was trained with data in a particular depth range. So even if you change the depth that the camera sees, the logic that converts that raw data into estimated skeleton poses may not accurately handle that input.